# Função para validar um CPF em R

Tags: r

Por favor, preciso de uma função em R para validar um CPF, ou seja, verificar se um número passado como parâmetro é um CPF válido.

Comment: E o que você já fez?

Comment: Quais seriam os critérios para o número ser um CPF válido?

Comment: Cadê o código onde vc esta com dúvidas

Answer (score 10):

Bom, já que ninguém respondeu, apesar de concordar com os comentários acima, hoje é domingo, aqui vai.
Em primeiro lugar, podia de fato ter incluído alguma informação sobre esse tal de CPF. Leia o comentário do Rafael Cunha outra vez. Eu que sou Português nunca tinha sequer ouvido falar de semelhante coisa. Na [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadastro_de_pessoas_f%C3%ADsicas) encontrei toda a informação necessária incluindo o [algoritmo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadastro_de_pessoas_f%C3%ADsicas#C.C3.A1lculo_do_d.C3.ADgito_verificador) que vou usar abaixo. Isso deveria ter sido o seu trabalho.

**Código.**
O código abaixo são três funções. A primeira, `cpf_dig_controle` calcula os dígitos de controle ou verificadores de um número de 8 dígitos. A função está vetorizada de modo a aceitar vetores numéricos como entrada. Se por acaso a entrada for de classe `character` a função em princípio também não se engasga mas não garanto isso.

```
cpf_dig_controle <- function(y){
    v1 <- 0L
    v2 <- 0L
    z <- as.integer(rev(strsplit(as.character(y), "")[[1]]))
    for(i in seq_along(z)){
        v1 <- v1 + z[i]*(9 - (i %% 10))
        v2 <- v2 + z[i]*(9 - ((i + 1) %% 10))
    }
    v1 <- (v1 %% 11) %% 10
    v2 <- v2 + v1*9
    v2 <- (v2 %% 11) %% 10
    c(v1, v2)
}
```

De seguida vêm duas funções, uma para gerar números CPF, com a devida formatação e outra para verificar a sua validade.

```
cpf_gerar <- function(x){
    g <- function(y, v){
        z <- strsplit(as.character(y), "")[[1]]
        z <- as.integer(c(z, v))
        res <- sprintf(fmt = "%d%d%d.%d%d%d.%d%d%d-%02d",
                             z[1], z[2], z[3], z[4], z[5],
                             z[6], z[7], z[8], z[9], z[10])
        res
    }
    v <- lapply(x, cpf_dig_controle)
    result <- sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) g(x[i], v[[i]]))
    result
}

cpf_validar <- function(x){
    f <- function(y){
        z <- unlist(strsplit(y, "\\."))
        v <- substr(z[3], 3, 6)
        v <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit(v, "-")))
        z[3] <- substr(z[3], 1, 2)
        z <- as.integer(paste(z, collapse = ""))
        list(x = z, v = v)
    }
    result <- lapply(x, f)
    valido <- lapply(result, function(r) unlist(lapply(r$x, cpf_dig_controle)))
    valido <- sapply(seq_along(valido), function(i)
                    result[[i]]$v[1] == valido[[i]][1] & result[[i]]$v[2] == valido[[i]][2]
                )
    valido
}

cpf <- cpf_gerar(c(12345678, 87654321))
cpf
#[1] "123.456.786-02" "876.543.210-07"

cpf_validar(cpf)
#[1] TRUE TRUE

cpf_validar(c("123.456.786-02", "876.543.211-07"))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```