# Como validar um CPF usando uma função no R?

Tags: r

Estou tentando melhorar o código do @Rui Barradas que está postado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241935/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-validar-um-cpf-em-r) como resposta, porém o mesmo não funciona para algumas situações. Após depurar o código, entendo que o problema se encontra na função `cpf_validar`, visto que a `cpf_dig_controle` funciona bem, mesmo inserindo 9 digitos e, a `cpf_gerar` pra mim está "ok". Já mexi em algumas linhas, porém não obtive sucesso. Caso alguém possa dar alguma contribuição:

```
# gerar digito de controle a partir de 8 digitos
cpf_dig_controle <- function(y){
v1 <- 0L
v2 <- 0L
z <- as.integer(rev(strsplit(as.character(y), "")[[1]]))
for(i in seq_along(z)){
v1 <- v1 + z[i]*(9 - (i %% 10))
v2 <- v2 + z[i]*(9 - ((i + 1) %% 10))
}
v1 <- (v1 %% 11) %% 10
v2 <- v2 + v1*9
v2 <- (v2 %% 11) %% 10
c(v1, v2)
}

# gerar CPF
cpf_gerar <- function(x){
g <- function(y, v){
z <- strsplit(as.character(y), "")[[1]]
z <- as.integer(c(z, v))
res <- sprintf(fmt = "%d%d%d.%d%d%d.%d%d%d-%02d",
               z[1], z[2], z[3], z[4], z[5],
               z[6], z[7], z[8], z[9], z[10])
res
}
v <- lapply(x, cpf_dig_controle)
result <- sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) g(x[i], v[[i]]))
result
}

# cpf gerado
cpf <- cpf_gerar(c("01861932", "01234567","12345678","11511611"))
cpf

# validar cpf
cpf_validar <- function(x){
f <- function(y){
z <- unlist(strsplit(y, "\\."))
v <- substr(z[3], 3, 6)
v <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit(v, "-")))
z[3] <- substr(z[3], 1, 2)
z <- as.integer(paste(z, collapse = ""))
list(x = z, v = v)
}
result <- lapply(x, f)
valido <- lapply(result, function(r) unlist(lapply(r$x, 
cpf_dig_controle)))
valido <- sapply(seq_along(valido), function(i)
result[[i]]$v[1] == valido[[i]][1] & result[[i]]$v[2] == valido[[i]][2]
)
valido
}

#cpfs gerados pela função cpf_dig_controle a partir de 8 digitos
cpf_validar(c("018.619.323-00","012.345.673-02","123.456.786- 
02","115.116.111-04"))

#cpf válido, porém a função o qualifica como FALSE
cpf_validar("288.065.030-57")
```

Comment: A função `cpf_gerar(28806503)` com os 8 primeiros dígitos do CPF que você usa como válido na última linha fornece um CPF diferente do que você está usando: `"288.065.035-07"`. A pergunta agora é como você tem certeza de que o CPF que você está usando é válido?

Comment: Rafael, bom dia. Entei validar o meu próprio CPF e da minha eaposa com a funcao CPF validar e a resposta foi FALSE. Fiz o teste do digito veeificador usando a sua funçao de digito verificador para os CPF citados acima e os digitos foram informados corretamente. Além disso fiz vários outroa testess uaando CPFs gerados pelo Devs. Por esta razão acredito que o problwma esta na função CPF validar. Tentei ajusta-lá, porém o conhecimento que poaauo hj não foi suficiente para que obtivesse êxito. Se pudesse dar a aua contribuição seria de grande valia. Obrigado

Comment: Carlos, rodando as funções, eu reparei que os dígitos verificadores gerados pela função `cpf_dig_controle` não estão indo para os dois últimos valores do CPF na função `cpf_gerar`. O primeiro dígito após o traço dessa função é sempre `0` (pelo menos em todas as vezes que eu a rodei), então pode ser que exista um problema na função `cpf_gerar`

Answer (score 3):

Eu fiz alterações nas três funções criadas pelo @Rui Barradas neste [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241935/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-validar-um-cpf-em-r).

Modifiquei o algoritmo gerador dos dígitos verificadores visto que quando colocava o meu CPF, os valores gerados não batiam. O novo algoritmo que utlizei foi o desse [site](https://www.geradorcpf.com/algoritmo_do_cpf.htm).

```
cpf_dig_controle <- function(y){
 v1 <- 0L
  v2 <- 0L
  num <- is.numeric(y)
  z <- as.integer(strsplit(as.character(y), "")[[1]])
  n <- length(z)
  if(num){
    if(n == 7){
      z <- c(0, z, sample(0:9, 1))
    } else{
      if(n == 8){
        z <- c(0, z)
      } else{
        z <- z
      }
    }
  } else{
    if(n == 8){
      z <- c(z, sample(0:9, 1))
    } else{
      z <- z
    }
  }
  for(i in seq_along(z)){
    v1 <- v1 + z[i]*(11-i)
    v2 <- v2 + z[i]*(12-i)
  }
  v1 <- v1 %% 11
  if(v1 < 2){
    v1 <- 0
  } else{
    v1 <- 11 - v1
  }
  v2 <- v2 + 2*v1
  v2 <- v2 %% 11
  if(v2 < 2){
    v2 <- 0
  } else{
    v2 <- 11 - v2
  }
  c(v1, v2)
}
```

Alterei a função `cpf_gerar` pois a mesma sempre colocava o número `0` como sendo o primeiro após o traço (-) no CPF.

```
 cpf_gerar <- function(x){
   g <- function(y, v){
     num <- is.numeric(y)
     z <- as.integer(strsplit(as.character(y), "")[[1]])
     n <- length(z)
     if(num){
       if(n == 7){
         z <- c(0, z, sample(0:9, 1))
       } else{
         if(n == 8){
           z <- c(0, z)
         } else{
           z <- z
         }
       }
     } else{
       if(n == 8){
         z <- c(z, sample(0:9, 1))
       } else{
         z <- z
       }
     }
     z <- as.integer(c(z, v))
     res <- sprintf(fmt = "%d%d%d.%d%d%d.%d%d%d-%d%d",
                    z[1], z[2], z[3], z[4], z[5], z[6], z[7], z[8], z[9], z[10], z[11])
     res
   }
   v <- lapply(x, cpf_dig_controle)
   result <- sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) g(x[i], v[[i]]))
   result
 }
```

Por fim, levei em conta as alterações feitas nas duas funções acima para modificar a `cpf_validar`.

```
cpf_validar <- function(x){
  f <- function(y){
    z <- unlist(strsplit(y, "\\."))
    v <- substr(z[3], 5, 6)
    v <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit(v, "")))
    z[3] <- substr(z[3], 1, 3)
    z <- as.integer(paste(z, collapse = ""))
    list(x = z, v = v)
  }
  result <- lapply(x, f)
  valido <- lapply(result, function(r) unlist(lapply(r$x, cpf_dig_controle)))
  valido <- sapply(seq_along(valido), function(i)
    result[[i]]$v[1] == valido[[i]][1] & result[[i]]$v[2] == valido[[i]][2]
  )
  valido
}
```

Ao realizar o teste com os cpf's que você tem certeza que são válidos e estavam dando `FALSE` nas funções antigas e após alterações para validar o `0` como primeiro dígito, obtenho:

```
cpf_validar("288.065.030-57")
[1] TRUE

cpf_gerar("018619326")
[1] "018.619.326-26"
cpf_gerar(018619326)
[1] "018.619.326-26"
cpf_validar("018.619.326-26")
[1] TRUE

cpf_gerar("012345678")
[1] "012.345.678-90"
cpf_gerar(012345678)
[1] "012.345.678-90"
cpf_validar("012.345.678-90")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Rafael, boa tarde.

Comment: Fiz alguns testes no código ajustado está validando mais cpf válidos agora, porém nos meus testes os cpf apresentam inicio zero, tem apresentado problemas. Veja:

Comment: > cpf_gerar("018619326")
[1] "018.619.326-26"
> cpf_validar("018.619.326-26")
[1] FALSE

Comment: > cpf_gerar("012345678")
[1] "012.345.678-90"
> # TESTE
> cpf_validar("012.345.678-90")
[1] FALSE

Comment: Carlos, esses casos estão caindo no problema que relatei quando o dígito inicial é `0` e não tive tempo de tentar contorná-lo. Por enquanto vou ficar te devendo

Comment: @CARLOSFALCÃO acho que consegui contornar os problemas que você encontrava.

Comment: Poxa que legal. Quando puder publique o código, por favor. Acredito que ele será muito útil pra muita gente. Abs

Comment: Já atualizei na minha resposta.

Comment: boa noite e bom domingo.

Comment: Meu amigo, melhorou muito.... está quase perfeito. A função validar CPF só está falhando com CPFs que começam com 2 zeros. Pelo que testei o problema está na gerar digito. quando tento gerar o digito verificador iniciando com dois zeros ele ignora um e aplica o algoritmo para os demais, dessa forma acaba calculando errado. Seguem os resultados:

Comment: cpf_validar("243.442.940-84")#teste ok
cpf_validar("001.647.550-04") #teste falhou
cpf_validar("009.421.270-80")# teste falhou
cpf_validar("769.926.630-70")# teste ok
cpf_validar("067.093.890-49")#teste ok
cpf_validar("099.890.090-74")#teste ok
cpf_validar("867.759.820-03")#teste ok
cpf_validar("360.890.880-30")#teste ok
cpf_validar("020.031.234-07")#teste ok
cpf_validar("060.284.457-62")#teste ok

Comment: É bem complicado trabalhar com zero a esquerda. Eu consegui contornar quando o CPF contém somente 1 e não pensei no caso de 2. Talvez uma saída seja incluir nas funções um argumento que indique se existe (e quantos são) zero a esquerda.